# grepping the output of a curl command within bash script

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I am currently attempting to make a script that when i enter the name of a vulnerability it will return to me the CVSS3 scores from tenable.

So far my plan is:

1. Curl the page
2. Grep the content i want
3. output the grepped CVSS3 score

when running myscript however grep is throwing the following error:

```
~/Documents/Tools/Scripts ❯ ./CVSS3-Grabber.sh                             
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  100 30964    0 30964    0     0  28355      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 28355
  grep: unrecognized option '-->Nessus<!--'
  Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
  Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

This has me very confused as when i run this in the command line i curl the content to sample.txt and then using the exact same grep syntax:

```
grep $pagetext -e CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.
```

it returns to me the content i need, however when i run it via my script below...

```
#! /bin/bash
pagetext=$(curl https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/64784)
cvss3_temporal=$(grep $pagetext -e CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.)
echo $cvss3_temporal
```

i receive the errors above!

I believe this is because the '--' are causing grep to think the text inside the file that it is an instruction which grep doesnt know hence the error. I have tried copying the output of the curl to a text file and then grepping that rather than straight from the curl but still no joy. Does anyone know of a method to get grep to ignore '--' or any flags when reading text? Or alternatively if i can configure curl so that it only brings back text and no symbols?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Grep filters a given file or standard input if none was given. In bash, you can use the `<<<` here-word syntax to send the variable content to grep's input:

```
grep -e 'CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.' <<< "$pagetext"
```

Or, if you don't need the page anywhere else, you can pipe the output from `curl` directly to `grep`:

```
curl https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/64784 | grep -e 'CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store `curl` response in a variable, just pipe `grep` after `curl` like this:

```
cvss3_temporal=$(curl -s https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/64784 |
grep -F 'CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.')
```

Note use of `-s` in `curl` to suppress progress and `-F` in `grep` to make sure you are searching for a fixed string.